# Optimal figure width when using Plotly Table

Tags: python, plotly

I am using `plotly` in order to create a table figure.

Here's code from their website:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                 cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                     ])
fig.show()
```

[image: Plotly table]

Using `fig.update_layout(width=300)`, I can shrink the size and get rid of white space.

[image: Plot with less white space]

I am wondering how can I figure out, what the optimal width is?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no function that optimizes the column width in the plotly table. The ratio of each column width can be determined by columnwidth, but it is not an optimization. See here for more [information](https://plotly.com/python/reference/table/).

Comment: Try adding it before the last line of code. `fig.data[0]['columnwidth'] = [5, 10];fig.update_layout(autosize=False)`

Comment: @r-beginners This only states that the second column's width is double the width of the first column. Not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I raised it as a real example that I explained in my comment. I understand that it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah sorry, misunderstanding!